# The bane of my existence: Command 'name' raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction (discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

This error has been the bane of my existence for a week strong.

I have created a discord bot with a single slash command, all it does is take the user input text and pass it to a function that calls an external api to a LLM based Q&A service for proprietary document.

This is the response from the api, which is a `str`.

```bash
...is a lightweight and unopinionated messaging protocol designed to facilitate the creation of modular cross-chain applications.

2.
With a growing number of blockchains and the rise of modular blockchain architectures, a lightweight communication protocol that can be implemented anywhere has become necessary. However, bridging teams are faced with a similar trilemma to blockchain developers wherein one of the following pillars must be sacrificed to optimize the other two: decentralization, security, and scalability. The trilemma dictates that any blockchain can optimize for, at most, two of the three parameters at any time. Bridges and communication protocols face a similar issue. While other...
```

Sometimes the response can be longer than this and on occasion code snippets.

Here are my project files in order (main.py, retrieval.py)

```py
# main.py

import asyncio
import discord
import typing
import settings
from discord import app_commands
import retrieval


def run():
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True

    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
    tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print("Logged on as", client.user)

        tree.copy_global_to(guild=settings.GUILDS_ID)
        await tree.sync(guild=settings.GUILDS_ID)

    @tree.command(name="name", description="description")
    async def faaq(
        interaction: discord.Interaction,
        text_to_send: str,
    ):
        # Check if the command is being used in the specific category or channel
        if interaction.channel_id == settings.CHANNEL_ID:
            response = retrieval.conversation_manager.get_response(text_to_send)

            await interaction.response.defer()
            await asyncio.sleep(30)
            await interaction.followup.send(f"{response}", ephemeral=True)
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message(
                "This command can't be used in this channel.", ephemeral=True
            )

    client.run(settings.DISCORD_API_TOKEN)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

```py
# retrieval.py
import requests
import settings

headers = {
    "x-api-key": settings.CHATPDF_API_KEY,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}


def qa_bot(question):
    data = {
        "sourceId": settings.SOURCE_ID,
        "messages": [
            {
                "role": "user",
                "content": question,
            }
        ],
    }

    response = requests.post(
        "https://api.chatpdf.com/v1/chats/message", headers=headers, json=data
    )

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()["content"]
    else:
        print("Status:", response.status_code)  # change to log
        print("Error:", response.text)  # change to log


# run chatbot in local enviroment
class ConversationManager:
    def get_response(self, query):
        response = qa_bot(query)

        return response


conversation_manager = ConversationManager()

# cli for local testing
while True:
    user_input = input("User: ")
    if user_input.lower() == "exit":
        print("Bot: Goodbye!")
        break
    response = conversation_manager.get_response(user_input)
    print("Bot:", response)
```

I have tried sending just plain string

```py
# main.py
await interaction.followup.send("plain old string", ephemeral=True)
```

And still end up with the same error, so i know it is not from the `response` string.

Comment: Perhaps obtaining the response takes too long, generally `defer` is used first. It could also be that `followup.send` should not take `ephemeral` parameter and rather `defer` as per the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

*Modified answer*

Turns out I was wrong with my previous answer D:

For me it works with normal text:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="test")
async def test(interaction:discord.Interaction):
    response = "Response"
    await interaction.response.defer()
    await asyncio.sleep(30)
    await interaction.followup.send(f"{response}", ephemeral=True)
```

Another solution is this:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="test2")
async def test2(interaction:discord.Interaction):
    response = "Response"
    await interaction.response.send_message("Question will be answered shortly",ephemeral=True)
    await asyncio.sleep(30)
    await interaction.edit_original_response(content=response)
```

Comment: Still getting the same error :(

Comment: @doordashcon I modified my response. Former one was wrong :D